# local time from UTC format for many locations

Tags: r, dplyr, zoo, lubridate

I need to get an adjusted timestamp based on location, for example

```
location <- c('New york' ,'san fransisco, CA', 'houston', 'Chicago, IL')
id <- c(1,2,3,4)
timestamp<- c('2012-06-15 05:43:34', '2012-07-15 05:43:34','2012-06-13 03:24:42', '2012-04-13 03:24:42')
df<- data.frame(location, id, timestamp)
```

I need to create a new column that converts the UTC timestamp format to the local time in that region. For example, new york and sanfransisco can have different times for the same time in UTC. I know you can do it row by row, using tz function, it can be quite time consuming as the records are over a million. Any suggestions on how I can do that?

Comment: You may need to have a format for `tz` that is admissible in the 'location' i.e. `with_tz(ymd_hms('2012-06-15 05:43:34', tz = "America/New_York"), "UTC")`

Comment: thanks, yes can i pass the location string to the tz function for each row,ymd_hms('2012-06-15 05:43:34', tz = "locartion[1]")

Comment: is there a way to overcome this?

Comment: these are typed data so they are not admissible format, there are almost a million records

Comment: May be check with `OlsonNames()` to find the corresponding match

Comment: I was checking the entries on `OlsonNames()`.  Not all the entries you have in location is not matching

Comment: Can you check how many unique 'location' are there in the dataset.  If it is small, you can create a key/value pair to replace the location is the permissible location

Comment: let me check and get back to you asap

Comment: It is around unique 30028 locations

Comment: Ohh, even in OlsonNames(), there is only `length(OlsonNames())#
[1] 592`.  I would imagine most of these locations cluster to some similar location

Comment: I am thinking of doing that, i got a timezone database but it doesn't go as deeper to the location level. may be i should do a geocoding, but there are some restrictions on how many i can get, thanks so much !!

Comment: yes thats right, they are user entered data, so there can be many new yorks with different typos etc.,

Comment: Ok, that makes it hard.  Try to check with `stringdist` to map similar ones to a single one

Comment: Do you have lat/long information with these records? If you do, you could use that to find time offsets.

Comment: @DuckPyjamas yes I do have lat and long information. How do I offset the time?

Comment: There must be a package out there that can use the lat/long to find the timezone, or at least to resolve the location to a proper city or state name that you can supply as the timezone. I don't use any such packages, so you'll have to look around.